# configuring a dc:dc regulator

Tags: power-supply, boost

I'm trying to set up an [lm2734](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2734.pdf) to regulate a VIN of 9V - 12.6V down to 5.0V. I'm a bit of a noob, and the sample configurations they provide don't have the 5.0V output scenario. My specific question is around configuring the VBOOST pin - they define it as needing to be `5.5V > VBOOST – VSW > 2.5V` for optimal performance, but my understanding is that the VSW pin goes back and forth between VIN and 0V (that being the theory of operation here). In another spot, they talk about using a zener in series with VIN to drop the voltage down. There, they talk about the limits on VBOOST needing to be

```
(VINMAX – VD3) < 5.5V
(VINMIN – VD3) > 1.6V
```

Where VD3 is the breakdown voltage of the zener.

What am I missing here? How do I figure out VSW? I'd like to understand the theory here, beyond just "use this configuration," though I do ultimately need to pick how do set it up. My hunch is that given VOUT of 5.0V, I can just run VBOOST directly off VOUT, without any additional circuitry, but I'm not sure why.

**EDIT** Elsewhere in the datasheet, I see a reference to

```
VSW can be approximated by:
VSW = IO x RDS(ON)
```

RDS(ON) is 300mO and IO would be somewhere between 500mA and 1A. It seems like this may be the answer, but I would still like confirmation / clarification from those better educated than I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datasheet is a bit confusing, in part because they use \$V_{SW}\$ for more than one thing. In this case, we're concerned with the voltage across the N-channel MOSFET switch when it is on.

If you use 1A for your maximum output current and 600m\$\Omega\$ for Rds(on), then \$V_{SW}\$ is 0.6V, so if you derive VBOOST from the 5V output, then

> 5.5V > VBOOST – VSW > 2.5V

is satisfied (VBOOST will typically be 3.8V with a 0.6V switching diode). It's nice and safely towards the center of the range. Even if the output voltage was towards the high side of the tolerance range and Vsw and the diode drop were low you'd never exceed 5.5V, so it's safe on the high side as well.

Note: Do **not** use the 300m\$\Omega\$ value for Rds(on) because that is "typical" (some units will be worse) and just as important (or more important), it's measured at Tj = 25°C, and you want to use the maximum value, which will be much higher when the chip is hot (which it will be at 1A output).